# Text template not working with some words

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I am building a CLI to generate code for an homemade API framework (right now to generate the controller part).
To do so, I am using template, but I saw that the template is generating nothing (an empty file), when I use words such as `package` or `func` in the template.

I want to build the following template:

```
package controllers

{{- range .Methods }}
    {{ if eq .Name "Create" }}
            func ({{ firstChar $.ModelName }}c {{ title $.ModelName }}Controller) Get{{ title $.ModelName }}(c *gin.Context) {
                {{ $.ModelName }}, err := store.Find{{ title $.ModelName }}ById(c, c.Param("id"))

                if err != nil {
                    c.AbortWithError(http.StatusNotFound, helpers.ErrorWithCode("{{ $.ModelName }}_not_found", "The {{ $.ModelName }} does not exist", err))
                    return
                }

                c.JSON(http.StatusOK, {{ $.ModelName }})
            }
    {{ else if eq .Name "Get" }}
    {{ else if eq .Name "GetAll" }}
    {{ else if eq .Name "Update" }}
    {{ else if eq .Name "Delete" }}
    {{ end }}
{{- end }}
```

Do you have any idea of how to make template working?

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. The template package doesn't care what the rest of the text is: https://play.golang.org/p/vbm0qTbAdlL

Comment: What JimB said; also adding `Option("missingkey=error")` in the code might reveal an error (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working, I just add `template.Must` before `template.New` and it's now working like a charm.

```
path := filepath.Join("templates", "controller.tmpl")
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("model").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(string(body)))

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := tmpl.Execute(&buf, selectedMethods)
    utils.Check(err)

    src, _ := format.Source(buf.Bytes())
```

Comment: `template.Must ` does not change how templates are handled. If it changes your program _at all_, it's going to panic because you weren't properly handling an error.